# In period Selection, it is taking range as wrong. For selected Years

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

1. This is the First Visual where it is not working, here i have highlighted the selected year and week selection, period selected, here if i select the week1 and some random end week number, in period selected range it is shwoing the 2024-2025. [image]
2. This is the second visual where it is working properly as, some random start week and end week i have selected with the same year as 2024. In Period Selected it is showing the proper year, without 2025. [image]

This issue is happeing same for 2025 year as well. but other than these two years, other years are wokring as expected.

1. Checked the Edit interactions.
2. Checked the DAX Measure for the period selected, this is the formula.

   *Period selected = FORMAT(MIN('dDate'[Date]), "d mmmm yyyy") & " - " & FORMAT(MAX('dDate'[Date]), "d mmmm yyyy")*
3. Checked the dDate table, in that i couldnt find any issue.

Expecting:
With that single selection of year, with the selected week numbers, espceially this issue is happening if we select the week number as "1" and some random end week number, the range it should should as 2024 only, but in period selected it is showing as the 2024-2025. but if we select the week-2 and some random end week number, the range is showing as the 2024 which is correct.